# Turkish keys on android keyboard

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to make a Turkish keyboard. I've found examples and made one with English characters. But I have no idea how to add Turkish characters like çÇiİıIüÜğĞşŞ.

```
        <Key android:codes="100" android:keyLabel="d"/>

        <Key android:codes="i dont know what code it is" android:keyLabel="ğ"/>
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need font that support Turkish.